# evaluating the double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I tried to calculate $\int _0^9 dx\:\int _{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\:y^2dy$ which yielded $c$ as in this integral has no particular value...when I plot the graphs for it's D however, a certain area does come up so the question should be solvable - while it apparently isn't...?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int^{\sqrt{x}}_{-\sqrt{x}}y^2\,dy=
\left[\dfrac{y^3}{3}\right]^{\sqrt{x}}_{-\sqrt{x}}=
\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3-\left(-\sqrt{x}\right)^3}{3} = \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3+\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3}{3} = \dfrac{2\,x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}
$$
$$
\int_0^9\dfrac{2\,x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}dx = \left[\dfrac{4\,x^{\frac{5}{2}}}{15}\right]^9_0 = \frac{324}{5}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int^{\sqrt{x}}_{-\sqrt{x}}y^2\,dy & = \left[\dfrac{y^3}{3}\right]^{\sqrt{x}}_{-\sqrt{x}} + C=
\\\\ & = 
\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3-\left(-\sqrt{x}\right)^3}{3}+C  = 
\\\\ & = \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3+\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^3}{3} +C = 
\\\\ & = \dfrac{2\,x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} +C
\end{align}
$$
$$
\int_0^9\dfrac{2\,x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} +C\ dx = \left[\dfrac{4\,x^{\frac{5}{2}}}{15}\right]^9_0 + \left[Cx\right]^9_0 = \frac{324}{5} + 9C
$$

Of course you're free to set up $C = 0$.

Comment: I do not think you have an additional free constant when evaluating an definite integral.

Comment: @Lykos Technically you should be right! But one can always set it as zero!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what c and d are referring to, but at first glance it seems like the notation is slightly ambiguous. I'm guessing it is supposed to be interpreted as $\int _0^9 \:\int _{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\:y^2dy dx$ (this interpretation is standard in vector calculus) in which case it does have a value (simply evaluate the innermost integral then the outermost one).

Comment: have you , ever, done multivariate calculus?

Comment: @Bak1139 not sure what you mean. What I'm saying is exactly what Lykos did.